# JQuery: adding class to element if it has text

Tags: jquery, css, class, addclass

I have a series of links in a ul. Some have text and some do not, eg:

```
<ul>
<li><a href="google.com">Google</a></li>
<li><a href="yahoo.com">Yahoo</a></li>
<li><a href="bing.com">Bing</a></li>
<li><a href="#"></a></li>
<li><a href="#"></a></li>
<li><a href="#"></a></li>
</ul>
```

I want to use JQuery to apply a class only to the a tags that have text in them.

So far I have this:

```
var buttontext =  $('ul a').text();

if (buttontext.length > 0){
$('ul a').addClass('buttoneffect');
}
```

But the class is still effecting all a tags. I was just wondering if someone might be able to point me in the right directions here?

Thanks

Comment: Can you just alert the value of buttontext and check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("ul a").each(function (i, e) {
    var $e = $(e);
    if ($e.text().length > 0) {
        $e.addClass("buttoneffect");
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks. Just curious does the i in that function auto increment or something? Whats the purpose of it?

Comment: @MeltingDog: you might want to get familiar with the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/each/): yes, the i argument is the index of the element in the list found by the selector.

Answer (score 1):

This seemed easiest when I wrote it:

```
$('a').filter(
    function(){
        var child = this.firstChild;
        if (child){
            return child.nodeType == 3 && child.nodeValue.length;
        }
    }).addClass('buttoneffect');​​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/uawBL/1/).

Or in plain JavaScript:

```
var aElems = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

for (var i=0,len=aElems.length; i<len; i++){
    var child = aElems[i].firstChild;
    if (child && child.nodeType == 3 && child.nodeValue.length >= 1) {
        aElems[i].className += ' buttoneffect';
    }
}​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/uawBL/3/).

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$('ul a').each(function()
               {                                        
                  if($(this).text()!='')    
                  {
                     $(this).addClass('buttoneffect');   
                  }
               });
```

Check http://jsfiddle.net/uawBL/11/